# Find all instances of a word and replace with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find all instances of the word "eNews" on a page and replace it with;

```
<span style="text-transform: lowercase;">e</span>News
```

I found a few other answers on here but they were all directed towards looking in specific classes. I tried using the all elements selector to find the word but the replace I've written just replaces the entire page:

```
$('*:contains("enews")').each(function () {
    $(this).html('<span style="text-transform: lowercase;">e</span>News')
});
```

Here is a fiddle of the sort of page set up with the word spread about the page:

https://jsfiddle.net/mxsmLLvm/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try replacing like:

```
$('*:contains("enews")').each(function () {
  $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/enews/gi,'<span style="text-transform: lowercase;">e</span>News'));
});
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/u9uL5xeb/